# Is there any way to do a comparison between two dataframes which have their column names in a separate dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataframe with column names as a and b and values as below:

col a : a1, a2, a3, a4, a5

col b : b1, b2, b3, b4, b5

My other two dataframes are having column names as a1, a2, a3 ... in one df and in the other b1, b2, b3 and so on...

**df1**

col a1 :  x rows

col a2 :  x rows .....and so on..

**df2**

col b1 :  x rows

col b2 :  x rows  ...... and so on...

both dataframes df1 and df2 has same number of rows and ideally should have the same data.

How do I check whether both the dataframes has same data or not?

If it does not have same data for a particular column, how do I get the comparison stuff where the values are not matching..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Input dataframes
data = {'a': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'],
        'b': ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

data = {'a1': ['3/11/2020','3/12/2020','3/13/2020',
               '3/14/2020','3/15/2020','3/16/2020'],
        'a2': [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12],
        'a3': [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
        'a4': [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
        'a5': [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

data = {'b1': ['11 Mar 2020','12 Mar 2020','13 Mar 2020',
               '14 Mar 2020','15 Mar 2020','16 Mar 2020'],
        'b2': [ 7,  8, 99, 10, 11, 12], # mismatch here
        'b3': [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
        'b4': [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
        'b5': [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Example tranformation
df1['a1'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['a1'])
df2['b1'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['b1'])

df2.columns = df1.columns

print(df1.equals(df2))

print(df1==df2)
```

**Output:**

```
False
     a1     a2    a3    a4    a5
0  True   True  True  True  True
1  True   True  True  True  True
2  True  False  True  True  True
3  True   True  True  True  True
4  True   True  True  True  True
5  True   True  True  True  True
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jakub, but the situation I'm concerned is a different one. For instance, df1 has source data and is one to one mapped to target data which is stored in df2.  So incase of a data mismatch I want to check which attribute is not matching .
E.G.  PLANT_CODE is in df1 and PlantCode is in df2. If in any row there is a mismatch, then I need to get the entire row from the two dataframes as output.

Comment: I am not understanding how this code does not suit your situation. Did you try running the code? It creates a new df_bool that gives a true if the attribute matches and a false for a mismatch.

Comment: This check may work on the skeleton level but when we need to dig deeper like apply a transformation on one of the columns and then do a comparison, then it may not help.
e.g. If in df1 all values are like AMU.12345 then in df2 only 12345 will be there as per requirement. So before doing a comparison we need to take care of those too.  For this purpose if we need we are also provided with the column names of both source and target as a separate df

Comment: How can you dig deeper in a dataframe? If you have a dataframe with five columns and six rows, it has 30 cells to compare. This method gives a True or False for each of those 30 cells in comparison to the 30 cells in the other dataframe. If one cell has a value of AMU.12345 and its corresponding cell in the other df is 12345, it will return False for that one cell out of 30. If that's not what you are looking for, you better reword the question you wrote.

Comment: Guess so....I need to re frame my question properly which I will be doing. Thanks a lot for your time Jakub..Cheers!!!

Comment: I did not understand your "12345 will be there as per requirement." Are you saying that if one cell has a value of AMU.12345 and the corresponding cell has a value of 12345, then those cells should be considered equal?

Comment: Exactly...Yes..!! We will be having the transformation details ; in this case we will be instructed to consider substring after occurrence of first '.'

Comment: Also (df1==df2).all().all() may not work given there are date fields and integer fields in my dataframe which is throwing an error 
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects..
Any suggestion on that?

Comment: Everything you said (substrings, dates, etc) can be done, but first you have to start with whether or not each cell is true or false. Also, dataframe columns have 'dtypes' which can be a date object, integer etc.